# Postman & Github Integration

Tags: postman

I am using GitHub repositories to back up my Postman collections in the form of JSON format.But, I am unable to integrate GitHub & Jenkins directly. Please confirm, Is there any way by which latest code which I have committed in GitHub in the form of JSON , can automatically get executed through Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

All you need to do is [configure Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/solutions/github/) to listen to changes on your Github repository.

The you can follow [this guide](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/integration_with_jenkins) or read up any of the numerous ways in which teams are using [Postman with Jenkins](https://www.slideshare.net/QASymphony/restful-api-testing-using-postman-newman-and-jenkins).